# error c2039 en xmemory

Tags: c, visual-studio

Estoy teniendo un pequeño problema con `pybind11` y es que lo estoy usando por primera vez, sin embargo he conseguido importarlo a un proyecto de Visual Studio. Sin embargo aunque mi código es muy simple:

```
#include"pybind11/pybind11.h"

int test(int a,int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

(me iba a disponer a usar la función test en un script de python, usando `PYBIND11_MODULE` sin embargo me he encontrado que intentando compilar ese código me salen 7 errores, todos son `C2039` y todos en `xmemory`, y no me atrevo a tocar ese archivo, si sirve de algo estoy trabajando con visual Studio 2022

Comment: se ha comido la mitad de la pregunta, al publicarla

Comment: al compilar eso me salen 7 errores en `xmemory`,todos C2039 y en distintas lineas

Comment: y no me atrevo a cambiar ese archivo

Comment: lo que ha echo es bugearse el formato :/

Comment: Pon EN la pregunta los errores que salen. Puedes [edit] todo lo que desees, incluso si termina cerrada.

Comment: al reabrir visual studio se quito ese problema

Comment: aunque deveria cerrar esta pregunta por eso